# Hyper-V CPU SNMP Monitoring

Tags: hyper-v

My apologies for a potentially silly question. In my work environment we run multiple VM's using Hyper-V. I poll these VM's SNMP using Observium mainly for graphing purposes. The Host machine is an Intel Xeon E5-2407 @ 2.4GHZ x2, my question is if I look at the graphs of the host machine's CPU, it peaks at around 8% CPU utilization. If I check the other VM's they look like:

VM1 - 4 vcore's - 50% / VM2 - 4 vcore's - 45% / VM3 - 2 vcore's - 50% / VM4 - 4 vcore's - 3%

Could it really be possible that the host machine is barely doing any processing even though the actual virtual machines are hitting 50% of their processing power? Do you think that the Hyper-V polling is incorrect? Anyone has any experience with this before?

I would appreciate any feedback, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Due to nature of virtualization, monitoring CPU utilization inside the VM isn't acurate. Short version: processor scheduling is maintained by hypervisor, so VM doesn't really know how much it consumes.
[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768535(v=bts.10).aspx) describes this in detail, if you want a solid overview.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!